# jsoup - получить текст и ссылки

Tags: java, jsoup

Из этой таблицы могу получить текст, но ссылки не получается

```html
<tr>
<td align="center">TEXT1</td>
<td><a href="/#">TEXT2</a></td>
<td align="right"><b>TEXT3</b></td>
</tr>
```

Код, который не полностью работает:

```
Element body = document.body();
Elements links = body.getElementsByTag("a");
Elements tr = body.getElementsByTag("tr");
for (Element row :tr) {
    if (row.select("td").size() == 3) {
        String nambe = row.select("td").get(0).text();
        String table_mini = row.select("td").get(1).text();
        String url =row.attr("href");

        String praice = row.select("td").get(2).text();
        dataTableList.add(new Table_article(nambe, url, table_mini, praice));
    } else {
        // data
    }
}
```

Comment: `String url =row.select("td").get(1).select("a").get(0).attr("href");`

Comment: Спасибо. Сработал код:

String url =row.select("td").get(1).select("a").attr("href");

Comment: Приведите код в чувства, как это вообще можно нормально прочитать?